# Upvoting question or answer edits

Tags: discussion, voting, editing

I've had a few edits to my posts recently, and all of them helpful.

Should we have some means of appreciating this?

Comment: So there are two issues here: Rep and Score.  It seems your concerned with the former, while the system is concerned with the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're welcome. This issue has been discussed in [this meta.stackoverflow.com question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278/adding-incentive-for-editing).